# Changing active member of union in constant expressions

Tags: c++, c++14, unions, constexpr, variant

Playing with `constexpr` and `union` I found out, that I can't change active member of an `union` in `constexpr`. Just one exception: `union` of empty classes.

```
constexpr bool t()
{
    struct A {};
    struct B {};
    union U { A a; B b; } u{};
    u.a = A{};
    u.b = B{};
    return true;
}
static_assert(t());

constexpr bool f()
{
    struct A { char c; };
    struct B { char c; };
    union U { A a; B b; } u{};
    u.a = A{};
    u.b = B{}; // error originating from here
    return true;
}
static_assert(f());
```

First function may produce constant expression. But the second can't. Hard error says:

```
main.cpp:23:15: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
static_assert(f());
              ^~~
main.cpp:20:11: note: assignment to member 'b' of union with active member 'a' is not allowed in a constant expression
    u.b = B{};
          ^
main.cpp:20:9: note: in call to '&u.b->operator=(B{})'
    u.b = B{};
        ^
main.cpp:23:15: note: in call to 'f()'
static_assert(f());
              ^
1 error generated.
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e4b498e4a1e4185)

1.) Is it possible to change active member of `union` in constant expressions?

I tried to destruct active member, but it is not allowed, due to destructors are not `constexpr` in general. Also I tried to use placement `operator new` (`::new (&u.b) B{2};`), but also unusccessfull. `reinterpret_cast` also not allowed in constant expressions. Altering members of common initial subsequence prohibited too.

2.) Are there a ways to make mutable (in sense of changing active alternative type) literal `boost::variant`-like type? How looks like its storage if it possible?

3.) Is it undefined behaviour to make assignment to non-active members of `union` of trivially copy-assignable types **at runtime**? Is it undefined behaviour to construct non-active member of `union` of trivially-copyable types using placement `operator new` avoiding preliminary destruction of active member **at runtime**?

#### ADDITIONAL:

I can change entire literal type `union`, but not its non-active member:

```
constexpr
bool
f()
{
    struct A { char c; };
    struct B { char c; };
    union U 
    {
        A a; B b; 
        constexpr U(A _a) : a(_a) { ; }  
        constexpr U(B _b) : b(_b) { ; }  
    };
    U a(A{});
    a.a = A{}; // check active member is A
    U b(B{});
    b.b = B{}; // check active member is B
    a = b;
    a = B{}; // active member is B!
    return true;
}
static_assert(f());
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6350e38cf7b00180)

Therefore for literal type `variant` of trivially copyable types conversion assignment operator would be `template< typename T > constexpr variant & operator = (T && x) { return *this = variant(std::forward< T >(x)); }`.

Comment: What are your compilation flags? I [couldn't reproduce it on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e6ea03bde1783bf).

Comment: [No repro](http://ideone.com/nUlkcO)

Comment: @n.m. I use [clang 3.7.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e4b498e4a1e4185)

Comment: This area of the standard is rather messy. Some revision of [P0137R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0137r0.html) should hopefully clean it up a little bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>Disclaimer: "active" is defined in [P0137R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0137r0.html).</sup>

> Is it possible to change active member of union in constant
>   expressions?

Not directly, since modifying a non-active member is prohibited - [expr.const]/(2.8):

> — an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) or **modification (5.18, 5.2.6,
>   5.3.2)** that is applied to a glvalue that refers to a non-active member of a union or a subobject thereof;

However, this wording seems defective, since it's indeed possible to "modify" a non-active member by assignment of another union object as shown in your example. In fact, the copy assignment operator performs a copy of the underlying bytes and the internal information about the active member:

> The implicitly-defined copy assignment operator for a union `X` copies
>   the object representation (3.9) of `X`.

---

> Is it undefined behaviour to make assignment to non-active members of
>   union of trivially copy-assignable types at runtime?

That's presumably fine for objects of a trivially copyable class type, since those have trivial destructors and copy constructors/assignment operators. Although underspecified, [CWG #1116](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1116) seems to imply that it's intended to work:

> We never say what the active member of a union is, how it can be
>   changed, and so on. The Standard doesn't make clear whether the
>   following is valid:
>
> ```
> union U { int a; short b; } u = { 0 };
> int x = u.a; // presumably this is OK, but we never say that a is the active member
> u.b = 0;     // not clear whether this is valid
> ```

Comment: Ping: Changing the active member of a union in constant expressions is now allowed in C++20. :)

Comment: Yes, original example is accepted in GCC and MSVC in C++20 mode: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Trj7833rK
And Clang refuses it probably because of this bug: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/51130